# symfony2 reverse year order in date field

Tags: date, reverse, symfony-2.3

I want to have **year** list in date field to be in **descending order**. I could not find option in Symfony reference http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html .

I have a feeling that this is not possible by only switching an option, but maybe I just did not found it?

If not possible - how it can be implemented differently? Extend data class or something?

#### Final solution

So the trick was to set `range` option using higher date value first. I set `'years' => range(date('Y') - 14, date('Y') - 60),`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'years' => range(date('Y') -13, date('Y') -100),` // for 13 to 100 years old people